# Pronouncing German words in English

Tags: google-text-to-speech

i'm using Google TTS to generate audio files in my native language German.

Unfortunately there are some Words like f.e. "laser" that are pronounced as a German word, but i want it to be pronounced as the English one.

Is there any way in SSML to make it possible or do i have to generate separate audio files and cut them together?

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<speak version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis
                 http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/synthesis.xsd"
       xml:lang="en-US">
  The French word for cat is <w xml:lang="fr">chat</w>.
  He prefers to eat pasta that is <lang xml:lang="it">al dente</lang>.
</speak>
```

Check out the following link:
https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/#edef_lang